# NextJS middleware to redirect to a custom page when navigating to a private route as an unauthenticated user

Tags: next.js

Currently I have this middleware in my project

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
export default async function middleware(
  req: NextRequest,
  event: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const isAuthenticated = !!token?.access_token;
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login') && isAuthenticated) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/private', req.url));
  }

  const authMiddleware = await withAuth({
    pages: {
      signIn: '/login',
      error: '/api/error',
    },
  });

  // @ts-expect-error
  return authMiddleware(req, event);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|logo.png|sw.js).*)',
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|images|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
};
```

I want to redirect to a custom page i.e "You are not allowed" when navigating to a private route. Currently it only redirects to login page.